# Python: Set X and Set Y all mappings injective and surjective

Tags: python

Set X and Set Y all mappings->
(without imports)

```
x=[0, 1],Y=[1,2]
=
[[(0, 1), (1, 1)], 
[(0, 2), (1, 1)], 
[(0, 1), (1, 2)], 
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]]
```

```
def maps(X, Y):
    if X==[]:
        return [[]]
    if X!=[] and Y==[]:
        return Y
    def product(*args, repeat=1):
        pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
        result = [[]]
        for pool in pools:
            result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
        for prod in result:
            yield tuple(prod)
    e=[]
    for i in product(*([Y]*len(X))):
        e.append(list(zip(X, i)))
    return e
```

this is what i have now but i want this for injective and surjective once so def mapinjective and def surjective

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions to filter the list of all possible mappings returned by the function you already have, e.g.

```py
def maps_surjective(X, Y):
    return [f for f in maps(X, Y) if set(y for x, y in f) == set(Y)] 

def maps_injective(X, Y):
    return [f for f in maps(X, Y) if len(set(y for x, y in f)) == len(X)]
```